# Armv5l Cross compiling static file size differences

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, armv7

I have been working on getting a small staticly compiled program for ARM.

I have staticly compiled with two different compilers

https://uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/0.9.30.1/cross-compiler-armv5l.tar.bz2
(cross-compiler-armv5l/bin/armv5l-gcc)

and

gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

Now, my question is, why does the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi compile my program to over 400kb and the uclibc binaries compile my program to 30kb?

This is a HUGE size difference and I am wanting to compile in armv7l but I can't find any binaries like ulibc has. Is there a way to cross compile straight from gcc to create the same effect as the uclibc binaries.

These are the flags I use:
-s -O2 -static

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to cross compile gcc so that it isn't inflating my binary by 10 times it size that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `glibc` is not intended to be statically linked. For a systemwide, dynamically linked C-library like `glibc`, correctness, speed and feature-completeness are much more important than code-size, since a) the sort of system `glibc` is intended for has paging, so only the needed parts must be in physical memory, b) The physical pages the library uses will be shared by multiple programs via virtual memory.

Comment: The system I am executing my binary on doesn't support the libraries for dynamically linking. Also it has not much space and I have many binaries to add. This becomes a problem. It works fine with armv5l with absolutely no issues. I was just wondering if there was a way to emulate what they did uclibc for armv7. I strictly need something that focuses on reducing filesize. @EOF

Comment: Don't use glibc if glibc doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to do it. I'm not fully worried about what's the "best" solution compared to what I was asking if it was possible and possibly for someone to point me in the right direction to figure out why these two compilers create such huge file differences and how to do this with armv7l

Comment: Surely 1) download or build an ARMv7 uclibc 2) link against it? What am I missing here? Generally, the mini-sysroot packaged with a cross-toolchain is like the crappy zinc-carbon batteries you get in the box with a new gadget - good enough to show it works, but needs replacing with the real thing for any serious use. Even if your target filesystem _is_ glibc-based, unless you've actually built the entire thing with with whatever random glibc version and kernel headers were provided, they're probably not appropriate anyway.

Comment: I see that crosstool-NG boasts support for various compact C library flavours, if you really wanted to build your own entire custom toolchain.

Comment: what is your definition of binary, the elf file or the actual flash memory image?

Comment: ELF.. Also to @notlikethat. Thank you I will look into it